# bash read from file and store in array

Tags: arrays, bash, file

Let's say i have a file that looks like this:

```
element1,element2  
element3,element4  
element5,element6
```

How can I read this file in bash and store it in an array as follows:

```
array={element1,element2,element3,element4,element5,element6}
```

Can someone help me with the code? Thanks!

Comment: The marked duplicate reads complete lines as array elements, here OP asks to read multiple elements per each line.

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore `read` altogether and simply use redirection after setting `IFS`, e.g.

```
$ IFS=$', \t\n'; a=($(<file)); declare -p a
declare -a a='([0]="element1" [1]="element2" [2]="element3" [3]="element4" \
[4]="element5" [5]="element6")'
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading line by line, then spliting by comma, you could do:

```
IFS=,$'\n' read -d '' -r -a array <file
```

This will:

- use `NUL` character as line delimiter (`-d ''`), and this way (if your file does not contain null characters) read the complete file at once
- split the "line" (i.e. the complete file) in fields using `IFS`, which is set to comma and newline, `IFS=,$'\n'`
- store all words/elements in `array`.

Output:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
element1
element2
element3
element4
element5
element6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this bash code:

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
  array+=("$line")
done < "$1"

echo ${array[@]}
```

This read the content of the file that you specify by argument line and reads line by line while stores the values in a bash array.

Bye!